# Matlab error function structure Error identifier

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I'm programming up a custom class and want to throw an undefined operator error (like would occur if you executed `{[]}*{[]}`). I know I need to make an error structure with the message, the stack, and the identifier. It's the last that I'm having trouble with, I don't understand how `MException` works. I tried out the following code

```
myError.stack = dbstack;
myError.identifier = MException('foo:noBar','You did not foo bar.');
myError.message = ['You did not foo bar.'];

error(myError)
```

but get the error

```
Error using error
Field "identifier" of input structure must contain a valid MATLAB message identifier.
```

But I don't know what valid identifiers are because the help section just seems to go in circles.

Is there a list of valid identifiers that I'm missing? Or some additional resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) command will create the `MException` object for you, and include call stack information. You should not create these yourself.

Simply call the `error` command with your new ID and message:

```
error('foo:noBar','You did not foo bar.');
```

If you really want to use a struct for this, put those two pieces of information into the `identifier` and `message` fields:

```
myError.identifier = 'foo:noBar';
myError.message = 'You did not foo bar.';
error(myError)
```

But this is just a more verbose version of the former. I guess this could be useful if you keep a struct array with errors, so you just need to do `error(myErrors(3))`, that way your messages and IDs will be consistent.